# Pointwise convergence implies $L^p$ convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: X \to [0, \infty) \subset \mathbb R$ measurable where $X$ is a measure space. Let $f_n : X \to [0, \infty) $ be simple functions (i.e. linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets) such that for each $x \in X$, $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$.

How can I prove that $$ \|f_n - f \|_p = \left ( \int_X |f - f_n|^p d \mu\right )^{1/p} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$$

I don't think this is right but if for $n > N_x$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon$, we can let $N = \sup_{x \in X} N_x$ to get $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \leq \varepsilon$ and then 
 $$ \|f_n - f \|_p = \left ( \int_X \|f - f_n\|^p d \mu\right )^{1/p} \leq \left ( \int_X \varepsilon^p d \mu\right )^{1/p} =  \mu(X)^{1/p} \varepsilon  $$

But $\mu(X)$ could be infinite so I'm not sure what to do.
 Thanks.

**Edit** What assumptions do I need to make this true?

Comment: Since $x \mapsto e^x$ is measurable, there exists a sequence of simple functions that converges to this exponential on $[0,+\infty)$. Of course the exponential is not integrable. Are you forgetting an additional assumption?

Comment: @Siminore Yes, $f_n \leq f_{n +1}$.

Comment: @bananalyst: Please edit the question to add this statement.

Comment: @bananalyst: Something is still missing; Siminore's counterexample still applies.  You can find simple functions in $L^p$ that increase to $e^x$.  So even with the additional statement this is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is: No, even on finite measured spaces.

For an example, consider $X=(0,1)$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure, and $f_n=2^n\cdot\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}$.

Comment: I forgot to write it in the question but I meant $f_n(x) \leq f_{n + 1}(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Should I post another question?

Comment: Then if $f_1$ is in $L^p$, this follows from Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Did you mean if $f_n$ is in $L^p$?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Right. I think I see it now. We can swap limit and integral and get the integral over the zero function.

Comment: Then I still don't understand.

Comment: Wait, wait... You know that 1. $f_n\geqslant0$, 2. $f_{n+1}\leqslant f_n$, 3. $f_1$ is in $L^p$--and you ask whether $f_n$ is in $L^p$?

Comment: No, the other way around: $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh I see. Then you must add the hypothesis that $f$ is in $L^p$, otherwise you could have $\|f-f_n\|_p=+\infty$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now. What I asked in the question follows easily from the monotone convergence theorem if $f \in L^p$.